# div width height according text?

Tags: html, css

I wana section box width height according text size. i try with below codes its working but not best width height of section box according to text. I design three css ids 1st is #wbp_row second is #wbp_col and last one is text id name is #threedtext

```
I try these codes with html5 and css3 techniques.
```

My css Code:

```
#wbp_row {
position:relative;
display:table;
border:solid 1px #0F0;
min-width:auto;
max-width:960px;
max-height:auto !important;

margin: 0 auto;

}
#wbp_col {
position:relative;
display:table-row;
width:320px;
min-height:auto!important;
border:1px solid #000;
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 0px;
padding:0;


}

#wbp_row #threedtext {
font-size:70px;
    max-height:auto !important;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
/*text-shadow: 0px 4px 0px rgba(82,82,82,.80),
         2px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 7, 0.50),
         3px 8px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.40),
         0px 12px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
         color: rgba(141, 198, 63, 1);
         padding:0;
         line-height:normal;
         overflow:auto;
         position:relative;
        border:1px solid #F00;

}
```

HTML Codes :

```
<section id="wbp_row">
<Section id="wbp_col">
<p id="threedtext">Web</p>
</Section><!--Cols codes end-->
<Section id="wbp_col">
<p id="threedtext">Brand</p>
</Section><!--Cols codes end-->
<Section id="wbp_col">
<p id="threedtext">Print</p>
</Section><!--Cols codes end-->
</section><!--row code end-->
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kx9Wq/ link created. I think conditional css will work.

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjan parida codes are not working as i require it expand height more!!!

Comment: but height not fit according text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set width:auto in "#wbp_col" like this

```
#wbp_col{width: auto;}
```

So section is adjust its height and width according to text size.

Comment: thanks @dheeraj...Your above code also helpfull me for remove bugs